# How can I do a string comparison in a while loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am populating an HTML control using a JavaScript while loop. I need to exclude a string value from the population. I am trying this code but it is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function getWebPropertiesSucceeded()
{
    var user = groupOwnerUsers.getEnumerator();

    while (user.moveNext())
    {
        if (user.get_current().get_title() != 'gps\ims sharepoint site collectors')
        {
            AddRowToTable(user.get_current().get_title());
        }
    } 
}
```

the `gps\ims sharepoint site collectors` value is still being added to my control. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: did you add logging and see why it fails?

Comment: Try to double slash sign  \\ in compared text

Comment: Thanks the double slash was the problem. Script runs as expected now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\` starts an escape sequence, replace with `\\`.